# hello guys i am using manim library for animations

Tags: python, animation, module, manim, algorithm-animation

```
from manim_imports_ext import*
class VennDiagram(InterractiveScene):
    def construct(self): 
      radius = 3.0
      c1,c2 = circles = Circle(radius= radius).replicate(2)
      c1.set_stroke(BLUE, 3)
      c2.set_stroke(YELLOW, 3)
      c1.move_to(radius*LEFT/2)
      c2.move_to(radius*RIGHT/2)t
      circles.to_edge(DOWN)
      self.add(circles)
      self.wait()
```

this is the code i want to run, but i got an ModuleNotFoundError: No module Named manim_imports_ext
how do i download this module. I tried replacing manim_imports_ext with manim but then it shows InteractiveScene is not defined.
Any help will be appreciated.

My animation code should run.

Comment: Did you install it with `pip install manim-ext` beforehand ?

Comment: as you said i intsall manim-ext but it too shows module not found named manim_imports_ext

Comment: I think you're looking for https://pypi.org/project/manimlib and then use this example : https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/master/example_scenes.py

Answer (score 2):

`manim_imports_ext` is an entrypoint module for some private, custom features that 3b1b uses for his videos, see https://github.com/3b1b/videos.

For the code you have posted, you actually don't need anything from these extensions -- `InteractiveScene` is a class shipped natively with `manimlib`, just replace your first line with `from manimlib import *` and render your file using the `manimgl` command line utility.